# Javascript vertically centering the active element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a carousel in my website I am doing, I need to implement a function that center the image vertically when item is active, the function is this:

```
function vertically_centred(first_box_id, second_box_id){
    window.onresize = function() {
        var height1 = document.getElementById(first_box_id).offsetHeight;

        var height = document.getElementById(second_box_id).offsetHeight;

        var total = (height / 2 ) - (height1 / 2);

        var color = document.getElementById(first_box_id);
        color.style.top = total + "px";
    };

}
```

i have 3 items with 2 box inside with different ids, the function works perfectly, however when carousel changes to the next item the function doesn't work i have implemented this function by adding this in my html file:

```
<script>
    vertically_centred('text-1', 'item-1');
    vertically_centred('text-2', 'item-2');
    vertically_centred('text-3', 'item-3');
</script>
```

I think it needs to detect if item is active then use the function and I do not know how to do it.

HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div id="item-1" class="active item">

            <div class="container">
                <div id='text-1' class="text-center-resizable">
                    <img src="images/welcome_img.png" alt="Cover">
                    Welcome test1
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="item-2" class="item">

            <div class="container">
                <div id="text-2" class="text-center-resizable">
                    <img src="images/welcome_img.png" alt="Cover">
                    Welcome test2
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="item-3" class="item">

            <div class="container">
                <div id="text-3" class="text-center-resizable">
                    <img src="images/cover.jpg" alt="Cover">
                    Welcome test3
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


    <a href="#myCarousel    " class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> </a>
    <a href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* This is for Big Screen the min size is 13px and the max when
    screen is bigger its 16px*/
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .text-center-resizable {
        font-size: 13px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .text-center-resizable {
        font-size: 16px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    }
} /* End of the class */
#myCarousel {
     background-color: #222;
     background-attachment: fixed;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     padding: 0;
 }
```

Comment: can you post `html` markup? and have you tried `color.style.position='absolute';`?

Comment: i have added the html file, the function works for the first item, but when item changes it doesnt work. it is not a problem of the css but on the script that doesn't work when it changes idk why

Comment: you still need to add the css for us to test and trace.

Comment: @Ryan the problem is not on he css because the function works fine, the problem is to detect which item is active so it can work on that item only.

Comment: If you show us your codes including HTML and what library you used, we would be able to suggest a better approach. You don't need to use JS for this kind of requirement.

Comment: @orland thanks and i will rollback my post because i already posted it like more than 10 hours ago what they asked for but i got no answer however i found solution by modifying the css but i wanna know how to do it with js

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem changing the it centered the element, if someone needs this in the future i will leave the code right down:

.

```
text-center-resizable {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Every time vertically_centred is called, it is just resetting the window.onresize function. So the previous values are lost. Try something like this instead:

```
function vertically_centred(first_box_id, second_box_id){
    var height1 = document.getElementById(first_box_id).offsetHeight;
    var height = document.getElementById(second_box_id).offsetHeight;
    var total = (height / 2 ) - (height1 / 2);
    var color = document.getElementById(first_box_id);
    color.style.top = total + "px";
}

function centerItems(){
    vertically_centred('text-1', 'item-1');
    vertically_centred('text-2', 'item-2');
    vertically_centred('text-3', 'item-3');
}
```

And then your next and previous buttons could be defined as:

```
<a href="#myCarousel" onclick="centerItems()" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> </a>
<a href="#myCarousel" onclick="centerItems()" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> </a>
```

Comment: that works but not in the way i need, because when item is changed it wont resize or center the image vertically, it will only work if windows is resized.

Comment: Why did your example have the code on window resize? Anyway, I changed my code so that it can be called when next and prev are clicked.

Comment: it resolves a part of the puzzle, have in mind that it will change automatically so no click is going to be done. so what about that? i would appreciate your answer if so. thanks

Comment: Are you using a third-party library for this carousel? What process is changing it automatically? Whatever it is you would need to hook into that event.